# Jekyll: Como importar e usar fontes JavaScript

Tags: jekyll

Bom dia galera !

Como importo uma pasta assets/fonts em meu projeto, e depois importo no CSS ? A questão né é importar o CSS, e sim como fazer esse import usando o Jekyll, para quando eu gerar o site as fontes venham também.

Obrigado

Comment: pode editar sua perguntar e reformular, está confusa. Obrigado.

Comment: ainda precisa da resposta ou já resolveu?

Comment: @VirtuaCreative Não consegui a resposta e parei de mexer no Jekyll. Em breve voltarei a usá-lo e atualizarei a pergunta, caso necessário.

Comment: Ok! Sugiro que não desista do Jekyll... Depois que a gente se entende com ele é uma maravilha!

Comment: Sem dúvida ! Estou sem falta de tempo mesmo :(. Voltando a usá-lo e resolvendo o problema eu coloco a resposta.